# Whats required for a question to be of high quality

Tags: discussion, scope

As the scope of this site is rather wide we will not run out of questions, but do we want to have them all?

- How short can a question be and still be acceptable?
- How detailed do you need to ask it?
- Is it necessary that you do have the problem yourself?

Answer (score 7):

I feel that we need very specific and actual problems that apply to yourself to be acceptable. The question should not be answerable sufficiently with common sense, that includes searching at least the SE Network for an answer before posting here.

That means, for a question to be of high quality you must:

- Define exactly the problem you have.
- Show why common sense is not enough to solve it, if applicable.
- State where you have already searched for an answer to the problem, if at all.

Your question should be able to have one best answer, just hearing out all the ways to do stuff is not good.

I think this Q&A needs a very hard line on whats ok as a question or it will be swamped in crappy questions.

Comment: Thank you for starting this, it's much needed at this point.

Comment: @MattS. Yes. The answer part to this even more so, there will be much cleaning up to do.

Comment: I think we need a close reason that closes the "common sense" questions but is phrased differently to be less ambiguous

Comment: @ZachSaucier There is no way we can ever define "common sense" in a way that all users would find meaningful. See my answer on the meta question for that close reason.

Comment: **One best answer** nothing in life **NOTHING** has one best answer, everything considered best can be bettered in future, so I disagree only with that part